# Не редактируются метки, написанные слитно через pipeline (|)

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, метки, правки

Начну сразу со скриншота, демонстрирующего о чем идет речь.

Так выглядит при просмотре вопроса:

[image: Просмотр вопроса]

А вот так при редактировании:

[image: Редактирование вопроса]

При удалении и добавлении меток, если они остались теми же, несмотря на то, что при редактировании мы видим их корректное отображение — при обычном просмотре все по-прежнему.

Помогает только удаление какой-то одной из меток и сохранение в таком виде.

Вопросы, демонстрирующие проблему:

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/401231/ [история изменений]
[Как переделать под адаптивную верстку текущий сайт?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/244635/)
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/246199/
[Runtime Error при запуске приложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/206035/)
[Неправильная работа оператора if](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/161776/)
[Как посчитать выражение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/128365/)

Comment: Вроде как, поправили!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это всё глюки импорта данных из Хэшкода. Есть и другие проявления:

- Игнорирование исправлений меток, если у вопроса короткий заголовок. Никаких сообщений об ошибках нет.
- Игнорирование отката к предыдущей версии или частичный откат, если предыдущая версия каким-то образом не проходит валидацию. Откат в истории отображается, но текст неверный.
- Рассинхронизация отформатированного текста на HTML и исходного текста на markdown, когда при редактировании поста в предпросмотре отображается совсем другой HTML.
- Рассинхронизация меток и закэшированных меток, когда при редактировании отображаются не те метки, как при просмотре поста.

База денормализованная: метки хранятся и как связи между таблицами, и как строки в постах. База с предвычисленными значениями: HTML, сгенерированный по markdown, хранится в базе, а не вычисляется каждый раз (для постов, но не для комментариев). В результате, если значения не соответствуют друг другу или не проходят валидацию на прикладном уровне, это приводит к таким мифическим глюкам.

Когда вы редактируете пост, проверяется, внесены ли какие-то изменения. Если изменений нет, то при нажатии на кнопку "Сохранить изменения" *ничего не происходит*. Более того, если изменяются только метки, то это тоже отдельный режим, и на изменения проверяются только метки, хотя валидируется весь пост.

Чтобы заставить движок сайта реально заново проверить и отредактировать пост, нужно изменить его текст. Когда я натыкался на подобные глюки во время последней битвы за чистоту меток, я добавлял в пост точку, а потом удалял её. Эта правка, несмотря на тривиальность, заставляет движок сайта полноценно обработать абсолютно все поля заново.

Answer (score 2):

Я когда видел такие вопросы, то изменял метку например на PHP, а потом делал откат версии к старой и все становится нормально.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/404521/revisions
Но это не решение конечно. Не делать же так с каждым вопросом.

Answer (score 2):

Больше похоже на какой-то новый глюк для импортированных вопросов, чем на старые битые данные. Потому что в кэше гугла метки выглядят нормально:

[ссылка на кэш](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:mFNXAiNP75MJ:ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/161776/%25D0%259D%25D0%25B5%25D0%25BF%25D1%2580%25D0%25B0%25D0%25B2%25D0%25B8%25D0%25BB%25D1%258C%25D0%25BD%25D0%25B0%25D1%258F-%25D1%2580%25D0%25B0%25D0%25B1%25D0%25BE%25D1%2582%25D0%25B0-%25D0%25BE%25D0%25BF%25D0%25B5%25D1%2580%25D0%25B0%25D1%2582%25D0%25BE%25D1%2580%25D0%25B0-if+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=by)

а вживую в том же вопросе - метки уже битые: [Неправильная работа оператора if](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/161776/)

Я бы предложил не трогать эти вопросы до ответа от администрации.